# How to hand over values to a double-pointer and print the values out as if it would be an multidimensional array? (C)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, nspointerarray

I have following struct defined which I can not change:

```
typedef struct _content {
    int length;
    char **lines;    
} content_t;
```

I initialized it in the main function like that:

```
struct _content cont;
cont.length = 6;
cont.lines[cont.length-1][255];
```

I try to assign a value to a certain element of the multidimensional array and also 
to print the value out- which doesn't work:

```
cont.lines[1][1] = "A";
printf("\n\n%c", cont.lines[1][1]);
```

What am I doing wrong here? 
Many Thanks

Comment: `lines` is not initialized, so you can't dereference it.

Comment: allocate memory for your char **lines first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int main(){

content_t cont;
cont.length = 6;
cont.lines=malloc(sizeof(char*)*cont.length);

for(int i=0;i<cont.length;i++) cont.lines[i]=malloc(255);

printf("\n\n%c", cont.lines[1][1]);


for(int i=0;i<cont.length;i++) free(cont.lines[i]);
free(cont.lines);


}
```

that's the right way to do it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. One more question: How can I assign a value to cont.lines[1][1] ?

Comment: just like that: inhalt.lines[1][1] = 'D';

Comment: You could also do something like this after the memory for each line is allocated: `strcpy(cont.lines[i], "hello");`